# Invoking stored procedure from hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I would like invoke a stored procedure from hibernate. My db is mysql.

```
StoredProcedureQuery procedureQuery = session.createStoredProcedureQuery("cancellaPalestra");       
procedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter("id",Integer.class,ParameterMode.IN);
procedureQuery.setParameter("id",p.getProfiloPalestra().getId());
```

The following exception occurs. I'm using 5.2.15 release, why NotYetImplementedFor6Exception appears?

> org.hibernate.NotYetImplementedFor6Exception: org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureParamBindings
> at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureParamBindings.getBinding(ProcedureParamBindings.java:73)
> at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureParamBindings.getBinding(ProcedureParamBindings.java:24)
> at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractQuery.locateBinding(AbstractQuery.java:824)
> at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractQuery.setParameter(AbstractQuery.java:949)
> at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.setParameter(ProcedureCallImpl.java:821)
> at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.setParameter(ProcedureCallImpl.java:71)
> at com.etabeta.gymnasium.dao.configurazione.profilo.PalestreDao.cancella(PalestreDao.java:112)
> at com.etabeta.gymnasium.biz.configurazione.profilo.PalestreBiz.elimina(PalestreBiz.java:72)
> at com.etabeta.gymnasium.rest.configurazione.profilo.PalestreBean.elimina(PalestreBean.java:111)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> [image]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
> at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
> at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:191)
> at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:102)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:205)
> at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:186)
> at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
> at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:252)
> at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:212)
> at org.apache.openejb.util.proxy.ProxyEJB$Handler.invoke(ProxyEJB.java:74)
> at com.etabeta.gymnasium.rest.configurazione.profilo.PalestreBean$$LocalBeanProxy.elimina(com/etabeta/gymnasium/rest/configurazione/profilo/PalestreBean.java)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.OpenEJBEJBInvoker.performInvocation(OpenEJBEJBInvoker.java:95)
> at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
> at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201)
> at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.OpenEJBEJBInvoker.invoke(OpenEJBEJBInvoker.java:68)
> at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104)
> at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.AutoJAXRSInvoker.invoke(AutoJAXRSInvoker.java:64)
> at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
> at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
> at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
> at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
> at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.doInvoke(CxfRsHttpListener.java:258)
> at org.apache.tomee.webservices.CXFJAXRSFilter.doFilter(CXFJAXRSFilter.java:99)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.EEFilter.doFilter(EEFilter.java:65)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
> at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

My config.xml:

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

Comment: Seems like you are using the development version of Hibernate even though you say you are using 5.2.12.  I downloaded the source and did a search for NotYetImplementedFor, and there is no reference for that substring.